# What types of enemies should I seek out to maintain a "Massacre" or "Kill Streak"?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are lots of enemies that continually generate mobs until they themselves are killed. One of my favorite parts of this game is seeing how large a kill streak I can achieve. It's a great source of fun, gold, items, and xp. What I want to know is this...

**What enemies should I seek out for this purpose?**

I'm looking for enemies with the highest mob spawn rate so I can feasibly just keep cutting them down.

**Where are they typically found?**

What act, quest, and area do you usually spot them? I know these areas are random, but a general idea or potential scripted event would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towards the beginning of Act III, you will find Fallen and some equivalent mages who can generate more Fallen.

If you avoid killing the mages, you can have fights that go on endlessly. It took me five minutes to fight my way down some stairs once because the Fallen would never, ever stop coming.

Comment: Now that I'm into Act IV, this was by far the best place to get a kill streak that I found.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, instead of looking for specific enemies or enemy types, I suggest one special event:

The [Jar of Souls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdf711kPnWw) will spawn a very large amount of skeletons, and you can also lure monsters from other areas of the crypts to the location of the event.

Other than that, the Carrion Nests come to mind, which can sometimes occur in groups of two or three and all spawn Carrion Bats, as seen here:

[image]

They occur in Act 1 randomly in many of the random dungeons, as well as in the Fields of Misery and around the Highlands.